# convert system.guid to system.guid?

Tags: asp.net, guid

I have this declaration in my code.

```
Guid? thisGuid = null;
```

I have also tried,

```
Guid? thisGuid = Guid.Empty;
```

There is section where Guid is referred:

```
Create(out thisGuid);
```

Also, other section:

```
this.abd.Fill(a,b, c, ref payGuid);
```

The conversion from Guid to Guid? is not taking place by either of above declarations. Also if i do not give Guid? than the Create() method throws an  error.

HELP ME SOLVE THIS!

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. What is your objective?

Comment: What is the exact error message? What is the `Fill` method code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a nullable type into a method that doesn't accept a nullable type (or vice-versa). I am assuming that both of the methods you showed take `Guid`s as parameters (because you haven't told us). If you want to then put that value in a `Guid?`, you have to copy it:

```
Guid thisGuid;
Create(out thisGuid);

// If you still want to put it in a Guid?
Guid? nullableGuid = thisGuid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert like this.

```
Guid? nullableId=(Guid?)YourGuid;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that it will not be `null` then you can use:

```
thisGuid.value
```

Answer (score -1):

The conversion from Guid to Guid? will take place now. Please try this code. 
Thanks.

```
Guid PureGuidId = Guid.Empty;
Guid? AllowNullableGuidID = (Guid?)PureGuidId;
```

Comment: The conversion from Guid to Guid? will take place. Please try. Thanks.